# Simple PHP Is IP in Subnet IF ELSE issue

Tags: php, ip, prefix, subnet

So i'm trying to check whether an IP is within as specific prefix or network. I've almost got this program running however my if else only echoes the first part even if you provide data that should return false. I wonder how I can resolve this problem. Thanks

I'm later echoing my ip_test (User input, IP, Network, Cidr).
I get these values through a form submission on an HTTP page than use the _REQUEST array.

```
<?php

//variables + assignment of user input on html form.
$net = ($_REQUEST['uname1']);
$pre = ($_REQUEST['uname2']);
$ipv4 = ($_REQUEST['uname3']);

   function cidr_match ($ip, $network, $cidr)
    {

        if ((ip2long($ip) & ~((1 << (32 - $cidr)) - 1) ) == ip2long($network)) {
        echo "IP address $ip is within $network/$cidr subnet.";
        }
        else {
             echo "IP address $ip is NOT within $network/$cidr subnet."; 

        }


    }

    echo "Subnet ID:" . $net;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Prefix Length:" . $pre;
    echo "<br>";
    echo "Subnet IP Address (IPv4):" . $ipv4;
    echo "<br>";
    echo cidr_match($ipv4, $net, $pre);

?>
```

Comment: This is a fairly well known function / if statement and it works well. Can you show us your other code that might be relevant (HTML form and however you are cleaning it and calling the function).

Comment: sure I'll make the edit.

Comment: I copied that exact code and am just passing the parameters in the URL: http://ryankempt.com/_test.php?uname1=192.168.192.0&uname2=32&uname3=192.168.192.100

Comment: Yes I see it showing up, however what if you enter bad data? Im using a FTP to upload and I see the results just like you've shown. My problem is when I add an IP outside that range my text does't go to the FALSE statement with the NOT within subnet...etc. You see?

Comment: I understand - give me some data that displays your problem, or use my URL and change the parameters so it displays error and send me the URL. I think you just need validation on the inputs as well, when I entered "x" as the prefix length it told me it was within the network range.

Comment: Oh I just got it working ha I don't know what it was! Thanks Ryan . My mistake.